# MySQL Syntax Error 1064 in Inner Join Query

Tags: java, mysql, syntax-error

Im using the following SQL query but i keep getting the error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''

```
SELECT roomID 
FROM rooms 
WHERE
 roomID NOT IN (
   SELECT t1.roomID 
   FROM
    rooms t1 
    INNER JOIN reservations t2 ON t1.roomID = t2.roomID 
    INNER JOIN reservationdetails t3 ON t2.resDeID = t3.resDeID 
   WHERE NOT ('2013-01-13' < t3.arrival OR ('2013-02-03' > t3.departure)
  )
```

I am not a very good SQL programmer.. did all that after reading up lots on SQL..

would be a great help if someone can figure out whats wrong in here..

thanks in advance..

Comment: Looks like you are missing another closing `)` after the `OR ('2013-02-03 > t3.departure)`

Answer (score 2):

It looks that, at least, you are missing `)`

Answer (score 1):

You missed a closing `)`

Change

```
WHERE NOT ('2013-01-13' < t3.arrival OR ('2013-02-03' > t3.departure)
```

to

```
WHERE NOT ('2013-01-13' < t3.arrival OR ('2013-02-03' > t3.departure))
```

Comment: shit.. thanks a million times guys!!! looks lyk no sleep got the better of me of missing that..  thanks again guys!!

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here

```
 WHERE NOT ('2013-01-13' < t3.arrival OR ('2013-02-03' > t3.departure)
```

try do it like that

```
 WHERE t3.arrival >= '2013-01-13'   OR t3.departure <= '2013-02-03'
```

Comment: `WHERE NOT (a OR b)` is equivalent to `WHERE (NOT a) **AND** (NOT b)`

Answer (score 0):

You should always close all opened brackets, seems like you missed one.

```
SELECT roomID 
FROM rooms 
WHERE
 roomID NOT IN (
   SELECT t1.roomID 
   FROM
    rooms t1 
    INNER JOIN reservations t2 ON t1.roomID = t2.roomID 
    INNER JOIN reservationdetails t3 ON t2.resDeID = t3.resDeID 
   **WHERE NOT ('2013-01-13' < t3.arrival OR ('2013-02-03' > t3.departure)**
  )
```

You can either remove the brackets between not and or like below

```
 WHERE t3.arrival >= '2013-01-13'   OR t3.departure <= '2013-02-03'
```

or add one more bracket..

```
 WHERE NOT ('2013-01-13' < t3.arrival OR ('2013-02-03' > t3.departure))
```